# Reverse Groups challenge at CodeEval.com

Tags: programming-challenge, objective-c, sorting

I am working through challenges at CodeEval.com and wanted to get your input on my code for this challenge.

> Given a list of numbers and a positive integer *k*, reverse the elements of the list, *k* items at a time. If the number of elements is not a multiple of *k*, then the remaining items in the end should be left as is.
>
> **Input sample:**
>
> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename. Each line in this file contains a list of numbers and the number *k*, separated by a semicolon. The list of numbers are comma delimited.
>
> E.g. input:
>
> ```
> 1,2,3,4,5;2
> 1,2,3,4,5;3
> ```
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> Print out the new comma separated list of numbers
>   obtained after reversing. E.g.
>
> ```
> 2,1,4,3,5
> 3,2,1,4,5
> ```

```
-(void)reversedGroups
{
    NSString *line = @"22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;3";   //input sample
    NSArray *lineArray = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSUInteger numbElements = [[lineArray lastObject] intValue];
    NSArray *elementsArray = [[lineArray objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray *resultLineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSUInteger pos = 0;
    while (pos<[elementsArray count]) {
        //itterating through the elements
        if (pos+numbElements <= [elementsArray count]) {
            //make sure that i have enough elements to reverse
            for (NSUInteger i = pos+numbElements; i>pos; i--) {
                //add elements in reverse to the result array
                [resultLineArray addObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:i-1]];
            }
        }else {
            for (NSUInteger j = pos; j<[elementsArray count]; j++) {
                //add elements that are left to the result array
                [resultLineArray addObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
        }
        pos += numbElements;  // move the postion by number of elements to reverse
    }
    //convert results array to string and add comma after each element as required for output
    NSString *resultString = [[resultLineArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@",resultString);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple task and I think code does its job well. I would point couple minor style issues:

- You don't need to use `objectAtIndex` method to access elements inside an array. `elementsArray[i]` is enough and it's more readable.
- You can access `count` property using dot-notation - `array.count`. Again, it's more readable.
- Combining result string from array looks cumbersome and complicated. And rely on `description` property. Why don't you create result string as you go without having to create temp array first?
- You are dividing `line` into lineArray. Then you're accessing first and last element using `lastObject` and `objectAtIndex:0`. I would prefer to use either `[0]` and `[1]` or `lastObject` and `firstObject`.
- Pass the code through standard Xcode formatter to clean up spacing and indentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I would use elementsArray[i] to access the elements but codeeval uses objc 2.0 and it returns an error.  I thought combining the result would be easier later to print the words with comma.  Next i would use a NSMutableString and just append in the code.

Comment: `firstObject` and `lastObject` should always be what you use when you can.